# Android: Using SSL/HTTPS to connect with PHP to database and use POST/GET

Tags: php, android, mysql, ssl, https

I used to make my connection to php for mysql with HTTP, Now I am asked to use HTTPS as it is more secure. but i tried too many ways but can't get the tablet to POST or GET any information, I made a self signed certificate and added to Local Computer trusted zone so i wont be asked that its is not verified do i want to continue, i tried connecting by browser and it worked fine and printed all the info that i needed, but not through the application. i attached my previous HTTP code that i need to change to HTTPS. would like some help to change this connection to HTTPS.

```
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost ("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/E-MENU/login.php");        
    username = etUser.getText().toString();
    password = etPass.getText().toString();
    password = md5(SHA1(password));

try{
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
    entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity!= null){

InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject (convertStreamToString(instream));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Log.e("body", body);
            HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.demo.com/login.php");

             nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);;


            Log.e("response", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            String aaa = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Content :"+ aaa, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
            is = entity1.getContent();

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Content :"+ (CharSequence) is, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }


public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

**MySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

**Add this if you working above 4.0 , in your code**

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: This sample uses a "null trust manager" which is very bad from a security perspective and therefore should be only used in test environments. Additionally this is in this case unnecessary as the certificate has already been added as trusted certificated.

Comment: @Robert : Whats is alternative ? can you please say

Comment: Read section "Using your own trust store: HttpClient" of http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: regarding "$ ./importcert.sh cacert.pem" openssl is not accepting it saying $ is not openssl command